# How do I properly setup VS Code in windows for debugging C++ programs using LLDB?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, llvm, vscode-debugger

#### My Development Environment

---

I recently setup VS Code to use it as a **LLVM `C++`** development environment. I wrote a custom task, using V.S. Code's built-in task interface, to automate the compilation process (my `./.vscode/tasks.json file can be seen below). Furthermore, I have downloaded & installed the following two extensions:

- ###### LLVM Debugger Extension
- ###### The CLangD Extension

#### The Issue

---

The project compiles, and it outputs an executable file, but it doesn't run. I also can't get the `.vscode/launch.json` file configured properly, and as a consequence, I can't run the debugger.

When I start the debugging process the executable file gets built but no useful info is provided in the VS Code debug console.
See

[image: VS Code Screenshot of failed LLVM attempt]

##### How can I get my c++ executable to debug at this point?

I included my launch.json file below, is there an erroneous line in it, or did I not add something I should have?

---

###### My `.vscode/launch.json` file:

```
    // @file ".vscode/launch.json"

    {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug C++",
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "terminal": "integrated",
        }
    ] 
}
```

---

###### Below is what my `.vscode/tasks.json` configuration looks like.

```
    // @file ".vscode/tasks.json"
    {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\clang++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g3",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\clang++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You should let the CodeLLDB extension create the launch.json for you.

Comment: If you got an Executable, your golden cowboy. Execute that baby by running it in PowerShell.